# Netbeans IDE 19 autocomplete not working as expected for curly brackets with JS

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autocomplete

I have a PHP project in Netbeans and whilst I can see autocomplete for my PHP code, it's not working as expected for JS, no matter if the JS is in a JS, PHP or HTML file.

For example, when I'm typing this out:

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    console.log("rah");
});
```

It's autocompleting the `()` and when I use the `.` so they are fine, it just seems to be when I then type the `{` - I expect it to give me a closing curly bracket but it doesn't.

I have also noticed that sometimes it doesn't want to suggest the closing HTML element, and instead defaults to putting in a `<!--comment-->` instead.  However, this seems sporadic!  However, when I type out `<script>` it doesn't give me an option to close that element, again defaulting to the `<!--comment-->`.

Within Tools > Editor > Clode Completion > HTML, I have all the options ticked.  For Javascript, I have All Possible Situations selected for the Enable Popup Completion Window and the Quotes Completion option is ticked.  I have the Code Completion Item Signature Char Width set to 40 but I'm not exactly sure what that is refering to.